# Why is this generic bounding illegal in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Imagine I extended the List interface to add a method as follows:

```
public interface MyList<E> extends List<E> {

    <R super E> MyList<R> castTo(Class<R> klass);

}
```

Why is this illegal? Am I just doing it in the wrong way because you should definitely be able to do this.

for example I would like to do something like the following:

```
MyList<? extends X> someList = // list from somewhere
MyList<X> xs = someList.castTo(X.class)
```

Comment: you mean `<R extends E>` not `<R super E>`

Comment: @YCF_L no I don't. I want to upcast the List

Comment: Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: They don't answer my question. I should be allowed to upcast to Object if I so desired. It does not contradict anything.

Comment: The "Bounding generics with 'super' keyword" seems to be a bit array-heavy. In this example, there are no arrays. Will not vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Someguy "I should be allowed to upcast to Object if I so desired." So then make the return type `List<Object>`

Comment: @Michael I was just commenting on why one of the resons in another answer doesn't apply. I should be allowed to upcast to any superclass.

Comment: Afraid I dupe-hammered it as the other answers *do* apply, as far as they can. (The upshot is there's nothing *logically* wrong with what you're doing, but the spec disallows it - probably because there's relatively few cases where it would be useful, and more cases where it could cause issues.)